# Remote server connection in neo4j using dotnet

Tags: neo4j

How to specify remote server while creating connection in neo4j using dotnet.

var client = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost/db/data"), "neo4j", "Pass@123");

This is working.

But when I specify IP Address it is throwing error.

var client = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://192.168.2.255:7474/db/data"), "neo4j", "Pass@123");

This is not working.

Answer (score 0):

What Neo version? What platform? Do you have any Firewall or routing restrictions between those servers/ports?

Verify the network / connection to that server from a browser.